# Existence of boundary fixing homotopy

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $f\colon \Bbb S^1\times [1,2]\to \Bbb R^2$ be a map such that $f(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)=f(2\cos\theta,2\sin \theta)$ for all $\theta\in [0,2\pi]$. Does there exist a homotopy $H\colon \Bbb S^1\times [1,2]\times [0,1] \to \Bbb R^2$ such that

$\bullet$ $H(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta,1)=f(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ for all $1\leq r\leq 2$. *I am thinking points of $\Bbb S^1\times [1,2]$ as pair $(r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta)$ for $1\leq r\leq 2$ and $\theta\in [0,2\pi]$.*

$\bullet$ $H(\cos\theta, \sin \theta,t)=f(\cos\theta,\sin \theta)=f(2\cos\theta, 2\sin \theta)=H(2\cos\theta,2\sin\theta,t)$ for all $t\in [0,1]$.

**My attempt:** I am trying to use the homotopy $H$ defied by $$H(r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta,t):=\begin{cases}f\left(\frac{r-1}{1-t}\cos\theta+\cos\theta,\ \frac{r-1}{1-t}\sin \theta+\sin\theta\right)&\text{ if }0\leq r-1< 1-t,\\ f(2\cos\theta,2\sin \theta)&\text{ if }0\leq 1-t\leq r-1\leq 1.\end{cases}$$

My problem is to check continuity; I am using pasting lemma on the line $r-1=1-t$. But the point $(r,t)=(1,1)$ is a problematic point for the quotient $\frac{r-1}{1-t}$.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put the interpolation outside $f$ for a much easier way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is "yes" and the desired technique is "straight-line homotopy applied to radial arcs".

Your notation is perhaps getting in the way of your understanding.  I suggest that you use a complex coordinate, as follows.  Set

$$A = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : 1 \leq |z| \leq 2 \}$$

This is an *annulus* in the plane.  Let $f : A \to \mathbb{C}$ be a continuous map.  We require of $f$ that, for all $w \in A$ with $|w| = 1$, we have $f(w) = f(2w)$.  (That is, $f$ is actually a map of a *torus* into the plane.) Your questions asking if we can homotope $f$, keeping various things fixed, until it becomes constant on radial arcs.

Comment: I have a question; as you suggested(also as I have done), there is no importance of $\Bbb R^2$ as **co-domain**, instead of replacing $\Bbb R^2$ with any other topological space will give the same answer. Am I right?

Comment: No.  For example, if the target (aka co-domain) is the two-torus $S^1 \times S^1$ then the desired homotopy may not exist.